# How do I save the number of times the user has lost the game in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

So every-time the user loses a game I want to add 1. I want to save the number of deaths the user has in the game. Right now the number just stays at 1 and doesn't go up when the user loses again. Why does this happen?

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

          var deathLabel = SKLabelNode()

          deathLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "LadyIce-3D")
          deathLabel.text = "100"
          deathLabel.zPosition = 14
          deathLabel.fontSize = 100
          deathLabel.fontColor = SKColor.darkTextColor()
          deathLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 1.1, self.size.height / 1.4)
          deathLabel.hidden = true
          self.addChild(deathLabel)

          }


       //EDIT

      if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && fourthBody.categoryBitMask == GameOverCategory {

        var deathScore: Int = 0

        deathScore++
        deathLabel.hidden = false

        var defaults=NSUserDefaults()
        var saveDeaths = defaults.integerForKey("saveNumberOfDeaths")
        if(deathScore > saveDeaths)
        {
            defaults.setInteger(deathScore++, forKey: "saveNumberOfDeaths")
        }
        var showNumberOfDeaths =defaults.integerForKey("saveNumberOfDeaths")




        deathLabel.text = String(showNumberOfDeaths)

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving simple values `NSUserDefaults` is a good choice.

The `setInteger:forKey:` method would probably meet your needs.

Comment: I tried using NSUserDefaults and everytime I lose the game it shows a zero only. I updated the code, Can you take a look at it? @Duncan C

Comment: Your code is wrong. Use the debugger to set through and figure out why it isn't working. You will learn more than if I tell you.

Comment: I tried it again now It goes to one but when I keep losing it doesn't go up. @Duncan C

Comment: @coding22 your logic is overcomplicated.  Think of it in steps of what you want to accomplish first and then code it.  1) Get current number of deaths from your user defaults.  2) Increment it by one. 3) Save the new value to user defaults. 4) Print the new value to your text label.

Comment: @Bek   The problem im having is incrementing by one when I start a new game and lose. It doesn't go up by one. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @Bek Is there anyway you could show me how to do this because I can't get past step 2